# asm calling a function with a std::string

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly, calling-convention

I can call a function with a char*.

But i am unable to call a function with a std::string

my program crashes when the std:: function trys to return.

```
const char* txt = "Hello world";
int myfunc1(char* s) {
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

std::string strtxt = "Hello world";
int myfunc2(std::string str) {
    std::cout << str.c_str() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    __asm {
        push txt
        call myfunc1;
        add esp, 4

        push strtxt
        call myfunc2;
        add esp, 4
    }
    return 0;
}
```

edit:
this is how visual studio calls it, im unsure on how to copy it to my code

```
00E88EF2 83 EC 1C             sub         esp,1Ch  
00E88EF5 8B CC                mov         ecx,esp  
00E88EF7 89 A5 CC FE FF FF    mov         dword ptr [ebp-134h],esp  
00E88EFD 68 10 53 E9 00       push        offset strtxt (0E95310h)  
00E88F02 E8 31 85 FF FF       call        std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > (0E81438h)  
00E88F07 E8 F2 87 FF FF       call        myfunc2 (0E816FEh)  
00E88F0C 83 C4 1C             add         esp,1Ch
```

Comment: You are definitely compiling for a 32-bit target that uses only stack-based passing, right?

Comment: its 32-bit and the 1st function is called and works

Comment: Have you tried looking at the assembly code output of a C++ call of `myfunc2()`?

Comment: yes and my guess is that i need to call `std::basic_string` some how before the function call?

Comment: I think what you're seeing there is a copy constructor call, because the `myfunc2` accepts its `std::string` parameter by value.

Comment: but wouldnt i need to call that copy constructor since thats how visual studio is calling it. im not sure on how to add that to my inline asm

Comment: Your function takes a `std::string` *by value*.  You only passed the first dword of the struct value.  That of course won't work.  It also probably won't work to pass a pointer to it unless you modify the function to take the `std::string` by reference.  Look at compiler-generated asm to see what the compiler does: https://godbolt.org/

Comment: yes i understand that, but im not sure how to convert it to my inline call

Comment: @PeterCordes how would i get the DWORD of the std::basic_string to pass in asm?

Comment: `sizeof(std::string)` is greater than 4.  It's not a single dword.  From your compiler's asm output, it appears that the 32-bit calling convention your compiler is using passes that large object by reference (i.e. passes an address).  Since you pass by value in the C source, it has to allocate a temporary / copy-construct that object.

Comment: @PeterCordes i mean the pointer to copy constructor

Comment: @PeterCordes why does this seem so hard, i have googled and googled and cant seem to find anyone calling a function with a std::string

Comment: `std::string` is not "trivially copyable" in C++ technical terminology; it has a copy constructor.  You can pass it by reference easily enough, but to really properly pass one by value you have to call its copy constructor, which is non-trivial to do by hand in asm.  The C++ compiler knows how to do that, but the asm function name is a mess of template stuff.

Comment: @PeterCordes so i cannot just get a pointer to the copy constructor and call it that way?

Comment: You don't need to get a function pointer to call a function.  It's templated, not virtually dispatched or anything.  But yes you *could* manually call the copy constructor and then pass a pointer to the newly constructed object to your function.  Much easier to pass by reference, though, so the function has a pointer to the original object.  Like `push offset strtxt` to pass a pointer to a global in static storage.  Change the function prototype to `int myfunc2(const std::string &str)`.

Comment: @PeterCordes how would i manually call the constructor?

Comment: With a `call` instruction, the same way the compiler does in the example in the question.  But presumably you'd have to type the mangled function name in the inline asm source?  I don't know, making function calls from inline asm is usually not a great idea in the first place.

Comment: @PeterCordes i dont think you understand what i mean, i dont know how to call the constructor in asm as i dont know how to get the pointer to it

Comment: @docasok733, you keep saying the same thing. You don’t need a pointer to the function to call it. All you need is its name. But since it is a C++ function, its name is not easy to write in assembly language.